# How can I get my bot to DM a specific user on command?

Tags: discord.js

I am wondering if my bot can send me a direct message after a user has sent a command. For example, let’s say a user sends a command and the bot replies to the user a message saying `please wait for admin` while the bot also sends me a direct message saying `a user has requested for help`. If there isn’t any way I can make that happen is there any similar way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send DMs like this:

```
user.send("Your message");
```

So it would look like this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

let client = new Discord.Client(),
    prefix = "!";

client.on("message", (message) => {

 if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {

  let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" "),
      cmd  = args.shift();

  if (cmd === "your_command") {

   message.author.send("please wait for admin");
   client.users.cache.get("your_user_id").send("a user has requested for help");

  }

 }

});
```

Comment: It said TypeError: client.users.get is not a function

Comment: Oh, i just edited my answer. It's `client.users.cache.get()` :)

Comment: If this worked, click on the check mark and mark this post as solved :)